# Can we customize the InputSplit size for the FileInputFormat

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Lets consider a MapReduce job which spawns 1000 map tasks. 
Block Size: 128MB
Minimum Split Size : 1MB
Maximum Split Size : 256MB

The block size seems to be the limiting value. Can we increase the split size beyond the block size?

This is a function from the FileInputFormat.java

```
protected long computeSplitSize(long goalSize, long minSize, long blockSize) {
    return Math.max(minSize, Math.min(goalSize, blockSize));
}
```

Based on the above function minimum split size greater than the block size will do what I want. Can someone throw some light on any side effects of setting the minimum split size in this way?

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to understand that `goalSize` refers to the total input size divided by `JobConf.getNumMapTasks()`. What this computation means is that:

- A split will be no smaller than the remaining data in the file or `minSize`.
- A split will be no larger than the lesser of the `goalSize` and the `blockSize`.

With that in light, you can understand that the ideal split size is exactly 1 block size, as it allows the framework to provide data locality to the task that processes the split. (source: [Pro Hadoop](http://www.springer.com/computer/book/978-1-4302-1942-2))

If you want to increase the split size beyond the block size, this means that each mapper will need to do remote reads to read the data that is not local, so this might be less efficient. But unless you're trying to create huge splits, I doubt this will have a critical impact on performance. I would still advise whenever possible to keep the default split size, unless you have a solid use case where this won't work.

Comment: "A split will be no smaller than the remaining data in the file or minSize." What is implied by 'remaining data in the file'? Also what is the purpose of mapred.max.split.size